# Pop up window with textbox after selecting checkbox

Tags: vb.net

all
I am working on a project with vb.net and MySQL database.
Now for taking information I have added few checkboxes, and in case if user selects a checkbox named other I want a window to appear and it should have a text box and when user enters the text at that box, the details should be stored in db.

Comment: There is nothing there to help with nor is there even a question.  Read [ask], take the [tour] and post the code you have and describe where you are stuck or what problem you are having.  We are not going to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't provided much information I may can't answer exactly your question but check if this can help.

First Add LINQ to SQL (.dbml File) - Let's name it as **XYZ** and Dataset (.xsd File) - let's name this as **XYZ** too, to your project and then drag and drop your database table in both the files and save all.

Now going into your form which contains the check box you mentioned.

Add this code to you checkbox click_event.

```
If checkbox1.checked = True Then
   Dim insertValue As String = ""
   insertValue = InputBox("Enter text to insert", YourTitle, "")
   If inserValue <> "" Then
      Dim db as New XYZDataContext
      Dim NewRec As New YourTableName With {.ColumnName = insertValue}
      db.YourTableName.InsertOnSubmit(NewRec)
      db.SubmitChanges()
      Msgbox("Value added!")
   End If
   checkbox1.checked = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

create your window in the designer and give it a name like someWindow. then in your code open the window from the click event of your checkbox. when you close the window don't dispose it. just hide it me.hide so when you window closes you can retrieve the data from your textbox.

```
    Sub Test ()
        Dim wd_SomeInfo as new someWindow
        wd_SomeInfo.showdialog()
        Dim result As String = wd_SomeInfo.txt_sometextbox.text
        If result = "" Then cancel....

    End Sub
```

Comment: you can make this window so you can use it for multiple inputs. Just change the input message in the form at runtime and you have your custom inputbox()